# Database of students in a social network

Tags: sql, mysql

This is sourced from the Stanford Coursera self study DB class SQL quizzes.

> Students at your hometown high school have decided to organize their
>   social network using databases. So far, they have collected
>   information about sixteen students in four grades, 9-12. Here's the
>   schema:
>
> ```
> Highschooler (ID, name, grade)
> ```
>
> English: There is a high school student
>   with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.
>
> ```
> Friend (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 is friends with the
>   student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if `(123, 456)` is in the
>   Friend table, so is `(456, 123)`.
>
> ```
> Likes (ID1, ID2)
> ```
>
> English: The student with ID1 likes the student with
>   ID2. Liking someone is not necessarily mutual, so if `(123, 456)` is in
>   the Likes table, there is no guarantee that `(456, 123)` is also
>   present.
>
> DB is [here](https://class.coursera.org/db/wiki/view?page=SocialData)
>
> Prompt: Find the number of students who are either friends with
>   Cassandra or are friends of friends of Cassandra. Do not count
>   Cassandra, even though technically she is a friend of a friend.

My answer (which works) is below, but I am wondering if there is a more succinct way of accomplishing the same results. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
select count(*)-1 from 
(
select id2
from friend f, highschooler a
where a.name='Cassandra'
and a.id=f.id1
union
select id2
from friend f, highschooler a
where a.id=f.id1
and f.id1 in ( select id2
from friend f, highschooler a
where a.name='Cassandra'
and a.id=f.id1 ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style

- Indentation would make your query more readable.
- Table names in MySQL [may be case sensitive, depending on the underlying filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134059/1157100).  Therefore, it is safest to write the query using identifiers with the same case as stated in the problem.
- SQL keywords are conventionally written in ALL CAPS, though some programmers object to that convention.
- Single-letter names for table aliases are cryptic.  While I can somewhat understand `friend f`, I have a harder time accepting `highschooler a`.

### Formulation

- `UNION`, short for `UNION DISTINCT`, [automatically deduplicates the result set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html).  If possible, prefer `UNION ALL` for efficiency.  However, in this case, you do need deduplication for the correct answer.
- The two halves of the union seem repetitive.
- Subtracting one from the final count is weird and risky.  I suggesting filtering out Cassandra herself from the result set.

Here's how I would write it:

```
SELECT count(Friend.ID1)
    FROM Highschooler AS Cassandra, Friend
    WHERE
        Cassandra.name = 'Cassandra'
        AND (
            Friend.ID2 = Cassandra.ID
            OR Friend.ID2 IN (
                SELECT Friend.ID1
                    FROM Friend
                    WHERE Friend.ID2 = Cassandra.ID
            )
        )
        AND Friend.ID1 <> Cassandra.ID;
```

Comment: Your `count` should probably be `COUNT`. Also, I think aliasing `Highschooler` to `Cassandra` is a little odd. It just seems more natural to say `WHERE Highschooler.Name = 'Cassandra'` than the alternative you suggested. The alias thing is a pretty personal thing though.